# pandas groupby count and proportion

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do something that I know must be basic pandas, but am racking my brain to figure it out. I want proportions and counts of each group to be available for an arbitrary level of group-bys:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'B': ['A'] * 4 + ['B'] * 4})

gb = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size()

prop_gb = gb / gb.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

`prop_gb` is now:

```
prop_gb
Out[116]: 
A  B
0  A    0.400000
   B    0.600000
1  A    0.666667
   B    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

I ultimately want this, though:

```
A  B        prop  count
0  A    0.400000      2
   B    0.600000      3
1  A    0.666667      2
   B    0.333333      1
```

I've tried merging the two `pandas.Series` objects, `gb` and `prop_gb` by converting them to dictionaries and "joining" them that way, but I know there must be a native pandas way to accomplish this...

This technically accomplishes what I want:

```
desired = {k: (v, prop_gb.to_dict()[k]) for k, v in gb.to_dict().items()}
desired
{(0, 'A'): (2, 0.40000000000000002),
 (0, 'B'): (3, 0.59999999999999998),
 (1, 'A'): (2, 0.66666666666666663),
 (1, 'B'): (1, 0.33333333333333331)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `to_frame` to create a dataframe to begin with and add the `prop` column:

```
>>> desired = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().to_frame('count')
>>> desired['prop'] = gb / gb.groupby(level=0).sum()
>>> desired
     count      prop
A B                 
0 A      2  0.400000
  B      3  0.600000
1 A      2  0.666667
  B      1  0.333333
```

Alternative, create a new frame from the 2 series:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(prop=prop_gb, count=gb))
     count      prop
A B                 
0 A      2  0.400000
  B      3  0.600000
1 A      2  0.666667
  B      1  0.333333
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do produce these values in one expression like so:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().agg(
  {'count': lambda x: x, 'prop':lambda x: x / x.sum(level=0)}
  ).unstack(level=0).reset_index()
#    A  B  count      prop
# 0  0  A    2.0  0.400000
# 1  0  B    3.0  0.600000
# 2  1  A    2.0  0.666667
# 3  1  B    1.0  0.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Concat the two series you've created:

```
df = pd.concat([prop_gb, gb], axis=1)
df.columns = ['prop', 'count']

df

         prop  count
A B
0 A  0.400000  2
  B  0.600000  3
1 A  0.666667  2
  B  0.333333  1
```